# Outputting the item item similarity matrix in mahout

Tags: hadoop, matrix, mapreduce, mahout, mahout-recommender

I have followed the recommendation engine example as given in chapter 6 of the Mahout in Action text book. Now while I get the output for the designated user,
Now is it possible to output the item-item similarity matrix computed during the 3rd Map reduce job. On completion of the MapReduce job I find there exists a `temp` folder which contains a directory called `/user/hduser/temp/similarityMatrix` however upon executing
`hadoop fs -cat temp/similarityMatrix/part-r-00000`  I get

```
SEQ org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable%org.apache.mahout.math.VectorWritable�h��8��Oh�pg;Q����@@����@@2����?�����@����?�&����@?�?�&   ����?�@?�&
                      ����?�?�@+�"���������?��D?�?�t�"�����
����@�?��?��?��?�?�����?�?��?��?�|�"�����
                                                    ����@(@�?��"?��?��?��?�
?�J?�΍��?��?�B�"���������?��M?�Ї��?��$?�!?�L�"�����!����@(@"�?�?�&?��@�?��?��@0@!?�)?�� ?��
                                   ?��
                                      ?��?��?�?�k?��?��ӯ�?��?��?�(?�?�F?�'?�!?��
     ?�
```

Is it possible in any way to output the item-item similarity matrix?

Answer (score 0):

This is a hadoop sequence file, a binary format. You need to write code to use it. Try mahout seqdumper on it to inspect the contents.

Comment: Type "bin/mahout seqdumper" for a help screen. This works for all mahout command line tools